# How to show a confirm message after delete in yii?

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

I am using Html::submitButton for a delete button and I need a confirm message after pressing the delete button.

```
<?= Html::submitButton('Delete', ['name' => 'delete', 'value' => 0, 'id' => 'delete1', 'class' => 'pull-left btn btn-danger']) ?>
```

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
<?= Html::submitButton('Delete', ['name' => 'delete', 'value' => 0, 'id' => 'delete1', 'class' => 'pull-left btn btn-danger', 'data-confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?']) ?>
```

Or

```
<?= Html::submitButton('Delete', ['name' => 'delete', 'value' => 0, 'id' => 'delete1', 'class' => 'pull-left btn btn-danger', 'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?']) ?>
```

Comment: I can do that only in 2 minutes :)

Comment: Upps..It didn't worked :( I mean, it asks the confirm question, but when I press "ok", it doesn't delete the item.

Comment: Did you try both?

Comment: Try it: `'onclick'=>"return confirm('Confirm, please.')"`

Comment: Yeah, I guess this works with 'onclick'. I am going to check it again.

Comment: Okay, Check now.